# google apps script returns 'undefined' error message but still completes

Tags: google-apps-script

To set the scene, here is the request I'm making via Google Apps Script...

```
function getHvdcData() {
  // call the API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dDomain + epHvdc, dParams);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(json);

  // define array location in response 
  var dataLevel = json['data']['hvdcFlow'];

  for (var i = 0; i <= dataLevel.length; i++) {
    var input = [];
    input.push(dataLevel[i].date);
    input.push(dataLevel[i].period);
    input.push(dataLevel[i].flow);
    input.push(dataLevel[i].direction);
    input.push(now = new Date());
    shtHvdc.appendRow(input);
  }
}
```

This is an example of what comes back in the response...

```
{
    resultCode:200, 
    message:"Success", 
    generated:"2018-11-07T14:00:46", 
    expires:"2018-11-07T14:05:46", 
    data:{
        hvdcFlow:[
            {
                date:"2018-11-07T00:00:00", 
                period:27, 
                flow:387.446, 
                direction:"North"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm hoping someone can help me understand why I'm getting  this message

> TypeError: Cannot read property "date" from undefined. at getHvdcData(demo_site:79)

Line 79 in my code singles out an attribute of a JSON response, which I'm then adding to an array which gets pushed to a google sheet (`input.push(dataLevel[i].date);`). I realise that I don't have lines in my code that specifically defined the attribute(s) but thought that was part of the JSON.parse function. The script is still able to read `.date` and add the associated value to `var input = [];` and insert it into the google sheet.

If the error is generated because I don't specifically declare what `.date` is, is there a way that I can turn off validation for this part of the code? Given that the script still inserts the data as expected, I wouldn't normally be concerned however I have also created a time based trigger for this to run. Currently, my executions are sitting at 100% Failed because of this and I'd prefer the Trigger Execution page only showed where my script failed to run.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue is that you try to retrieve the element from out of array, because the start of index of array is 0. Can you modify from ``for (var i = 0; i <= dataLevel.length; i++) {`` to ``for (var i = 0; i < dataLevel.length; i++) {``, and try again?

Comment: Try using the for each loop..
`for(var r in dataLevel){var row = dataLevel[r]}`

Comment: for completeness @Tanaike, replacing `<=` with `<` has worked a treat, i no longer get the original error message. thanks

Comment: for completeness @JobinJoseph, on another request i make from the same google sheet, i took your suggestion and replaced `for (var i = 0; i <= dataLevel.length; i++)` with `for (var i in dataLevel)` and that request also runs without the same error. thanks for providing a more succinct method.